# Pip Installation Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am a beginner in programming with Python. I have installed Python 3.6.1, and when I try to install `pip` (or any other package), this error appears (both in the command and shell):

```
  install pip
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried also with `pip -m pip`, but nothing, still the same error.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

To install a Python package, you need to be in the command line as @MohideenibnMohammed suggested. You cannot install a package from within a Python script using `pip`.

You have installed Python 3.6.1 which will have `pip` already installed so you don't need to try and install that again.

Next, you need to make sure that Python is added to your PATH.

1. Open Start Menu and right click My Computer. Click on Advanced System Settings.
2. Click on Environment Variables
3. Find the system PATH variable and click Edit. You want to add Python to this PATH variable by adding exactly ;C:\Python36  (assuming that is where you installed Python)

Go back to the command line and type in `pip install numpy` (you can use `pip3` instead of `pip` if you wish)

Comment: thanks for your help guys! I'll try to do this today :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use pip command in `python console` instead of terminal.

or check your command again .. `pip install package`
otherwise try this,

use `pip3 install package`  to install instead of `pip install package`

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but this appears all the time

Comment: >>> pip install numpy
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install numpy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: if its solved your issue accept the answer may help others

Comment: i think you trying from python console. get back from  it try the same from your terminal

Comment: while in the command prompt this appears: 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: if you are usign pip3 it will work or you need to install. but i think the problem is your trying to install from console instead terminal ...

Comment: @JamesPietroZanzarelli "pip is not recognised as an internal.........." this means that you need to add python to your PATH

Comment: @DavidG there is invalid syntax . i think he try to install from python console not from terminal or command prompt

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Yeah you're right that was his first problem. Then he said when trying it in command line he gets the "pip is not recognised" error.

Comment: no its pip3 not pip ... i suggest one of the solution using pip3 but i noticed he using python console later